# Free JSP/Spring MVC Web Hosting Site

Tags: web-hosting, looking-for-hosting, jsp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I am thinking of hosting a small web application built using Spring MVC.  Does anybody know any free web hosting sites that supports JDBC also?

I haven't tried web hosting site so I would like to know one site which sites are free and ok.
My app wont take so much disk space and would like to know if there are sites that runs on Tomcat.

Thanks.

Comment: there are a lot of these questions already.

Comment: I don't see what this question has to do with programming *per se*.

Answer (score 2):

Cloudbees' [Run@Cloud](http://www.cloudbees.com/run.cb) (formerly stax.net) is currently free.  I don't know how long that will remain the case, however.  It appears to support Spring MVC and JDBC.

Comment: @William Thanks. Sounds cool but I notice that its free until feb only 2011.  Its March now, but not sure if it will be paid.  Any other hints? Thank you.